# KeyDown with Click Event

Tags: forms, winforms, powershell, events

I have run into a bit of a snag for a form I am working on. I have a button that prompts the user with yes/no boxes and I want to add functionality that will allow them to bypass the prompt if they hold down the shift key when clicking the button. Here's what I have tried within the Click event `scriptblock` so far but nothing seems to be working:

```
    if($_.KeyCode -eq 'Shift'){
        #Stuff
    }

    if($_.Shift){
        #Stuff
    }
```

Any ideas what I can do to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click event doesn't have keycode. The following works in PowerShell v2 - there might be easier ways in later versions.

```
function Get-KeyState([uint16]$keyCode)
 {
   $signature = '[DllImport("user32.dll")]public static extern short GetKeyState(int nVirtKey);'
   $type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Name User32 -Namespace GetKeyState -PassThru
   return [bool]($type::GetKeyState($keyCode) -band 0x80)
 } 

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms 
$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button.Text = 'hi'
$Form.Controls.Add($button)

$button.add_Click(
    {
        $VK_SHIFT = 0x10
        $ShiftIsDown =  (Get-KeyState($VK_SHIFT))        

        if ($ShiftIsDown){
            [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Hi, you clicked the button with shift." ,"My Dialog Box")
        }
        else{        
            [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Hi, you clicked the button without shift." ,"My Dialog Box")
        }

    }
)

$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Any better solutions for PS v3?